# Sending 2 JSON objects to Django with Ajax

Tags: json, django, ajax

I'm trying to send 2 arrays via Ajax to my Django backend.

They are basic lists of dicts like:

- send_products = [{'product': some_text, 'orden': some_value}, .........]
- send_categories= [{'category': some_text, 'orden': some_value}, ........]

**The AJAX call**

As I researched around the web, I'm trying

```
        data = { 'category': send_categories, 'products': send_products, };
        data['category'] = JSON.stringify(data['category']);
        data['send_products'] = JSON.stringify(data['send_products']);

        $.ajax({
            url:'/website/save-catalog-order/',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",

            data: data,

            success:function(response){
                
            },
            error:function(){

            },
        });
```

**My target Django view**

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def SaveCatalogOrderView(request):

    category = request.POST['category']
    
    data = {}

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

> **Result**: I get an "MultiValueDictError: 'category'

If I try `category = json.loads(request.POST['category'])`

> **Result**: I get an "MultiValueDictError: 'category'

If I try `category = json.loads(request.POST)`

> **Result**: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not QueryDict

I usualy send 1 Json obeject POSTs without any problem But I can;t find the way to send 2.

Any clues welcome!

**UPDATE**

If I `console.log(data)` I get the correct info:

[image]

And the detailes info of one of the arrays:

[image]

Comment: What is the first line of your AJAX call for? You are overriding those values in the next 2 lines.

Comment: Just was trying to make the exaplanation clearer

Comment: If that is not actually part of your code you should remove it. You should also show the HTML form you are using. There is no such thing as a `MultiValueDictError`, only `MultiValueDictKeyError`, which implies that the key is not actually in your POST dictionary. You can add a `console.log(data)` before you make your POST request to see what is being sent to the server.

Comment: @voodoo-burger I'm not using a form. Just generate the array in javacsript. Just updated the post with the console.log result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

In my Ajax call I do

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'category': send_categories, 'products': send_products, }),
```

Then in the view

```
input_json = json.loads(request.body)
category = input_json['category']
products = input_json['products']
```